# I am using gTTS with winsound in python, the file is saving, but it makes the windows sound

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to make it save a .wav file that says "Good morning." It does this, waits two seconds, then plays a windows sound. I am using Python 3.7.2 and operating on Windows 10.

```
from gtts import gTTS
import winsound
import time

tts = gTTS(text='Good morning', lang='en')
tts.save("good.wav")
time.sleep(2)
#it works until here
winsound.PlaySound("good", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because, **winsound** module only works with **wav** file format and **gtts** only saves in **mp3** format, so you need to use some module that can play **mp3** format like **vlc** module.

I tried the same using vlc module and it works.

you can install vlc package

```
pip install python-vlc
```